# Update values from two different tables on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

This is my **table_start** on MySQL database :

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| userID | userTfc | userCount |
+--------+---------+-----------+
| 11655  | SN10    |        45 |
| 11655  | SN16    |        80 |
| 11655  | SN24    |       796 |
| 11655  | SN35    |        56 |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

I need update the **table_end** on the same MySQL database in this mode :

```
+--------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+
| userID | userTfc_01 | userTfc_01_Count | userTfc_02 | userTfc_02_Count | userTfc_03 | userTfc_03_Count | userTfc_04 | userTfc_04_Count |
+--------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+
| 11655  | SN10       | 45               | SN16       | 80               | SN24       | 796              | SN35       | 56               |
+--------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+
```

For the same **userID** I need update :

1. the *first* value of **table_start** column **userTfc** to column **userTfc_01** of **table_end**;
2. the *first* value of **table_start** column **userCount** to column **userTfc_01_Count** of **table_end**;
3. the *second* value of **table_start** column **userTfc** to column **userTfc_02** of **table_end**;
4. the *second* value of **table_start** column **userCount** to column **userTfc_02_Count** of **table_end**;
5. the *third* value of **table_start** column **userTfc** to column **userTfc_03** of table_end;
6. the *third* value of **table_start** column **userCount** to column **userTfc_03_Count** of **table_end**;
7. the *fourth* value of **table_start** column **userTfc** to column **userTfc_04** of **table_end**;
8. the *fourth* value of **table_start** column **userCount** to column **userTfc_04_Count** of **table_end**;

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Comment: You can execute query by using loop from the data of first table.

Comment: @RaviRoshan Thank you, do you have example? Loop in server side language ?

Comment: Yes.  I can post loop example hint using php as server side  if you wants

Comment: @RaviRoshan, Okay , thank you! I use ASP NET C# as a server side language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First execute this query for your first table

```
$query1 = "SELECT userTfc,userCount FROM  table_start WHERE userID='11655' ";
```

I am assuming after above query you got the result in an array lets say $result. Now you can update your second table using loop. For example :

```
if(!empty($result)){ // check if array is not empty
for ($i=1; $i <= sizeof($result); $i++) { 
    $query2 = "UPDATE  table_end  SET userTfc_0'".$i."' = '".$result[$i]['userTfc']."' WHERE userID='11655' ";
    mysql_query($query2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query. Use order by , limit and offset of mysql.  Order by your query then use limit to get one record and use offset to pick line number.

```
update table_end te 
set userTfc_01 = (select userTfc from table_start ts where ts.userid = te.userid order by userTfc limit 1 offset 0),
set userTfc_01_Count = (select userCount  from table_start ts where ts.userid = te.userid order by userTfc limit 1 offset 0),

set userTfc_02 = (select userTfc from table_start ts where ts.userid = te.userid limit 1 offset 1),
set userTfc_02_Count = (select userCount  from table_start ts where ts.userid = te.userid order by userTfc limit 1 offset 1),

set userTfc_03 = (select userTfc from table_start ts where ts.userid = te.userid order by userTfc limit 1 offset 2),
set userTfc_03_Count = (select userCount  from table_start ts where ts.userid = te.userid order by userTfc limit 1 offset 2),

set userTfc_04 = (select userTfc from table_start ts where ts.userid = te.userid order by userTfc limit 1 offset 3),
set userTfc_04_Count = (select userCount  from table_start ts where ts.userid = te.userid order by userTfc limit 1 offset 3) 
where the.userid = 11655
```

Comment: I have updated answer could please check it. Whether it is working or not. there is a typo in my query.